# Ghostscript PDFMARK external link on last page

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm converting a series of Illustrator files into a single PDF document using Ghostscript.

In that generated pdf document, I'm trying to apply an external link to the **last page** of the file. To do that I've created a separate **script.ps** with the following rules:

```
[ /Rect [0 0 528 771]
/Page 5
/Action << /Subtype /URI /URI (http://www.adobe.com) >>
/Border [0 0 2]
/Color [.7 0 0]
/Subtype /Link
/ANN pdfmark
```

I'm using the following to generate the PDF...

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -o output.pdf script.ps -f 01.ai 02.ai 03.ai 04.ai 05.ai
```

This creates a link on the first page only. So it seems to ignore the **/Page 5** I wrote in the script.ps file.

How do I apply the link on the last page of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are executing the pdfmark **before** you execute the remaining page descriptions (by the way, beware of using Adobe Illustrator '.ai' files, these are not guaranteed to be valid self-contained PostScript).

At the time you execute the pdfmark, there are **no** pages yet defined, so there's no way to translate the page number into the PDF object number which will contain the description of page 5.

Try running your 'script.ps' as the **final** operation, not the first.

Comment: Thanks KenS. You mean like this...
**gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -o output.pdf -f 01.ai 02.ai 03.ai 04.ai 05.ai script.ps**

Because I've tried this and I don't get a link at all. Is that because it's mixed in with the files to process? Is there a way to declare this a pdfmark?

Comment: That was what I meant, yes. It doesn't matter that its at the end, its all part of the same input stream as far as the pdfwrite device is concerned. You already have 'declared it as a pdfmark' because you've used the pdfmark operator.

Comment: OK so in fact you cannot specify the page like that in a pdfmark for pdfwrite. Same reasoning as in my answer, the pdfwrite device doesn't know until the end of the input what the object numbers are going to be. In your case, however, you can stick your 'script.ps' file in between the pages, immediately before the page you want it to appear on, and it will work.

Comment: Aaah! Thanks, KenS! That works. Sorry for the delayed response on this

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this and my solution was to use `/SrcPg` rather than `/Page`.

Example:

```
[ /Rect [0 0 528 771]
/SrcPg 5
/Action << /Subtype /URI /URI (http://www.adobe.com) >>
/Border [0 0 2]
/Color [.7 0 0]
/Subtype /Link
/ANN pdfmark
```

The order of input files then doesn't seem to matter.